# Print spool service appears to cause Explorer to hang - how to fix this?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash, print-spooler

I'm encountering a strange problem. A few days ago, my primary printer (Samsung ML-2950) unexpectedly stopped working with a "0 % toner" message. One file was in the print queue at that time. Right after that incident, it became impossible to open "Devices and Printers" or even right-clicking on anything in Explorer - Explorer would immediately stop responding.

I checked the error log and found that Explorer crashes waiting for spoolsv.exe, so I tried (as Admin) to clear the print queue by going to `%WINDIR%\system32\spool\PRINTERS`, but I was denied access to `PRINTERS` - and since I can't right-click on it because that crashes Explorer again, I couldn't even figure out who Windows would give access to that directory...

I then tried the Troubleshooting wizard, selected Printer problems, and the wizard immediately got stuck at "Checking for spooling service errors..." and has been stuck there since.

Any idea what I could do now? How can I access an object's properties without right-clicking it, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I've somewhat got this covered:

I opened `services.msc`, stopped the print spooling service, deactivated it and then rebooted.

Then I was able to delete the contents of `%WINDIR%\system32\spool\PRINTERS`. I reactivated the print spooling service, rebooted again, and now everything seems to work *as long as I keep my Samsung printer turned off*. When it's on, it appears to confuse the print spooler. Well, let's see what happens when I buy and install a new toner cartridge...will update in a few days.

Comment: ...and with a fresh toner cartridge, everything worked well again. Very strange behavior...